# nodejs peepcode tutorial - can't get it to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, pug, express

I bought the latest nodejs peepcode tutorial and followed it, however I can't get past the initial step.

I'm getting frustrated after spending several hours to find out where I got an error since debugging nodejs is a riddle for me.

app structure looks like this:

```
example 
  |__public
  |__views
  |__assets 
  |__apps <- instead of routes
  server.js
  package.json
```

Here is my simple code:

server.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
require('coffee-script');

var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// routes
require('./apps/authentication/routes')(app);

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
```

/apps/authentication/routes.coffee:

```
routes = (app) ->

    app.get '/login', (req, res) ->
        res.render "views/login",
            title: 'Login'
            stylesheet: 'login'

module.exports = routes
```

apps/authentication/views/login.jade template:

```
form(action='/sessions', method='post')
  label
    | Username
    input(type='text', name='user')
  label
    | Password
    input(type='password', name='password')
  input(type='submit', name='Submit')
```

nothing fancy, i got a stylesheet file and login.css in public/stylesheet/login.css
instead of a login template from authentication/routes.coffe when browsing http://localhost:3000/

```
Cannot GET /
```

no any other error message from node either:

```
Express server listening on port 3000 in development mode
```

I can't figure out where the problem is and this is really frustrating.
Probably some dumb typo somewhere but I can't figure this out :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a route configured for the root '/'. Navigating to http://localhost:3000/login should return your login view as specified by the route to the resource '/login'. You need to add something along the lines of:

```
app.get '/', (req, res) ->
  #if not logged-in then send to /login else
  res.render('/views/authenticated', 'Home', 'index')
```

For more details on routing see http://expressjs.com/guide.html#routing.

Comment: funny thing is peepcode tutorial doesn't say s**t about it, but localhost:3000/login does not work either. already tried that as well

Comment: Well you are right. I had a typo I didn't seen before and now /login route works. Really annoying. Any tips on debugging such mistakes in nodejs?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Goin to check it out. I've noticed that it's implemented into TextMate JavaScript-Tools Bundlle ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like everything is working as intended. The problem is that you haven't defined a route that matches the request `GET /`. You've only defined a route matching `GET /login` in your `routes.coffee`; also, `GET /anythinginyourpublicdir` will work thanks to the `express.static` middleware.

Comment: OOpp. Sorry you are right Trevor. I had a typo I missed before. Now the /login link works. Had to add {#__dirname}/views/login in routes.coffe. Really stupid thing. Any tips on debugging things in nodejs?

Comment: @PJJ I'd say that Node is hard to debug mainly because it's so heavily async. Definitely understand how JavaScript's event model works. (Plug: I've [written a book](http://leanpub.com/asyncjs/) on the subject.)

Comment: Bought it 5 min ago ;) Thanks for the tip. Any other reads to check out?

Comment: @PJJ You might want to correct "{#__dirname}/views/login" to "#{__dirname}/views/login" for anyone coming here and copy/pasting.